# In Oracle SQL , how do I show a 0 as a result even for rows where it doesn't return any values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following WHERE clause :

```
WHERE  prla.CREATION_DATE >= '13-JUN-14'    
                    AND  P.effective_start_date >= 
                    ALL (SELECT p_temp.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                    FROM HR.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F p_temp
                    WHERE P.PERSON_ID = p_temp.PERSON_ID)
                    AND P.current_employee_flag = 'Y' 
                    AND pha.APPROVED_FLAG = 'N'
```

My issue is with the `APPROVED_FLAG` part .  It will only return a 'N' value for one of the rows.

But it simply returns nothing as a result.

i.e . this is how my query looks before adding the `pha.APPROVED_FLAG = 'N'`

[image]

And here's how it looks after:

[image]

But it should look like so:

```
Oconee, SC       0
Oconee, SC       0
Oconee, SC       0
Owenton, KY      0
Owenton, KY      0
Owenton, KY      0
Waseca, MN       1
```

i read about a COALESCE function in oracle , would this help :?

Comment: Do you have an inner join that should be an outer join? Or an outer join that your `WHERE` clause is converting to an inner join?

Comment: @HABO - hmm ,  I don't think so . I will look into it. I may just be making a really dumb mistake here somewhere ! thanks

Comment: `and ( pha.APPROVED_FLAG = 'N' or pha.APPROVED_FLAG is NULL )` or `and Coalesce( pha.APPROVED_FLAG, 'N' ) = 'N'`? If either of those work it indicates that you have an `OUTER JOIN` on `pha` and should have included the `APPROVED_FLAG` test in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you take that out of the where clause and then just use a case statement or a decode statement to display what you want?

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT   1 AS id,
                          'Jackson, MS' AS city,
                          2 AS Num,
                          'Y' AS approved_flag
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   2,
                          'Libery Lake, WA',
                          27,
                          'Y'
                   FROM   DUAL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT   3,
                          'Oconee, SC',
                          89,
                          'N'
                   FROM   DUAL)
SELECT   id, city, DECODE (approved_flag, 'N', 0, Num) AS Num
  FROM   mytable
```